# How to merge selected elements of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as

```
$array = array (
0 => array( 'name' => 'zero'), 
1 => array( 'name' => 'one'), 
2 => array( 'name' => 'two'), 
3 => array( 'name' => 'three'), 
4 => array( 'name' => 'four'),
5 => array( 'name' => 'five'),
6 => array( 'name' => 'six'),
);
```

and I need to merge some elements according to a pattern

```
$pattern = array(
array('from'=>1, 'to'=>2, 'note'=>'something'),
array('from'=>3, 'to'=>5, 'note'=>'something'),
array('from'=>6, 'to'=>6, 'note'=>'something'),
);
```

How can I merge the elements to get an array of

```
$ result = array(
['0'] => array('name'=>'zero'),
['1,2'] => array('name'=>'one+two', 'note'=>'something'),
['3,4,5'] => array('name'=>'three+four+five', 'note'=>'something'),
['6'] => array('name'=>'six', 'note'=>'something'),
);
```

I understand that I should iterate one array in a loop and check the other one for the corresponding element to create a new array, but which one should I iterate?

Comment: you want the array key to be an array?

Comment: @treyBake no array key is not important as long as preserving the order. I just need to mix some elements according to the given pattern.

Comment: it is - if you're wanting arrays for array keys, that can change a lot of the code

Comment: So _anything_ that is not covered by one of the intervals in $pattern would have to land in the first array in the result? Even if you had an additional 7 / `seven` in your input array? Or would that have to become an additional half-entry at the end then?

Comment: @04FS 7 will be like 0 in the example. The main array is the first one. Nothing is removed from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array keys aren’t actually important, then I’d go about it like this:

```
$result = $processed = [];

foreach($pattern as $p) { // loop over the patterns
  $temp = [];
  for($i = $p['from']; $i <= $p['to']; ++$i) { // loop over from -> to
    $temp[] = $array[$i]['name']; // collect names of those items
    $processed[] = $i; // store index of item as an already processed one
  }
  $result[] = ['name' => implode('+', $temp), 'note' => $p['note']];
}

$temp = [];
foreach($array as $key => $item) {
  if(!in_array($key, $processed)) { // if index is not in list of already processed items
    $temp[] = $item['name'];
  }
}
array_unshift($result, ['name' => implode('+', $temp)]); // add to front of result
```

That will get you a result of the form

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => zero
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => one+two
            [note] => something
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => three+four+five
            [note] => something
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => six
            [note] => something
        )

)
```